# npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, npm-request

When i try:
$ npm install -g cordova@latest
always get
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead

mac Os Sierra 10.12
npm v. 4.4.4
node v. 6.10.2

Before install of cordova:
$npm list -g node-uuid
/usr/local/lib
....(empty)

After:
$npm list -g node-uuid
/usr/local/lib
....cordova@6.5.0
........cordova-lib@6.5.0
............npm@2.15.12
................request@2.74.0
....................node-uuid@1.4.7
............request@2.47.0
................node-uuid@1.4.8

I tried follow every suggestion and install/uninstall a hundred times.
It's a npm or cordova problem?

Comment: Its problem with cordova. They're using deprecated module.

Comment: simply ignore the warning...in the npm world you have a lot of these kinds. The fix should be done by cordova itself...

Answer (score 19):

This warning means that old node-uuid module is deprecated and won't be maintained moving forward. The module is still published in NPM for backward compatibility (with the deprecation notice).
We can explicitly install uuid module using below commands:

```
npm uninstall --save node-uuid
npm install --save uuid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
npm install uuid
```

Read More  : https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation : "In many cases, new features and bug fixes are available only with the latest version of the Firebase CLI and the firebase-functions SDK. It's a good practice to frequently update both the Firebase CLI and the SDK with these commands inside the functions folder of your Firebase project"

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
npm install -g firebase-tools
```