# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted installing ionic 3 and cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic3

I am trying to install ionic 3 and cordova for the first time in my desktop.
I am using windows 7.

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
```

shows me this error :

```
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
C:\Users\amir\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> C:\Users\amir\AppData\Ro
C:\Users\amir\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic -> C:\Users\amir\AppData\Roam
npm ERR! path C:\Users\amir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\no
.json
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\amir
s\fsevents\node_modules\ansi-regex\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\a
ules\fsevents\node_modules\ansi-regex\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:
\ionic\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\ansi-regex\\package.jso
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\amir\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_module
i-regex\\package.json' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

I tried entering windows PowerShell in administrator mode but the problem is not solved.
Any idea please ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem.

It is not about node-uuid.

I just go to appData/Roaming/npm and i deleted

> node-module folder

and

> npm cache

and then, It worked

Answer (score 3):

The answer is here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44150369/6291722 
node-uuid@1.4.8 is an old module, you need to upgrade it, or upgrade NodeJs itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, fixed it by downgrading npm from 5.4.0 to 5.3.0.

```
npm install npm@5.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem under different circumstances (I was trying to run `npm publish` which used to work correctly).

I solved it by upgrading npm with `npm install -g npm`. This installed npm@6.9.0.

Answer (score -1):

Running as admin worked for me ! :)

Comment: This isn't an answer. It's a comment at best.

Comment: @hrokr- Agree with you, but looking at his reputation I can say he doesn't have that privilege.